How do I configure a local machine to use another local machine's dnsmasq to resolve local domains?
I have a local area network (LAN). I recently set up a dedicated, physical, bare-metal server in this network that is running OpenShift (Red Hat's version of Kubernetes). The server, which is running OpenShift, is also running dnsmasq to resolve all of the OpenShift routes (subdomains) on that machine only. The problem is that I want to be able to access said OpenShift routes from a separate workstation physical machine on my LAN. I have read instructions and watched videos about dnsmasq, however, they only show me how to setup dnsmasq on the server machine. What do I need to do to:
A) Expose the dnsmasq service to my workstation machine via the LAN
B) Program my workstation machine so that when I try to browse to e.g. https://console-openshift-console.apps.my-cluster.local, it knows to query the DNS server (dnsmasq) running on the server machine in order to resolve this and other subdomains to the OpenShift server.
In other words, dnsmasq is doing it's job when I browse to those domains and subdomains on the server itself, but from other physical local machines, I can reach the server's IP directly, but domain resolution is not happening.


Expose the dnsmasq service to my workstation machine via the LAN

Add the auth-server= option for the domain you want to expose.
Also add a firewall rule to pass port 53 (both TCP and UDP).

Program my workstation machine so that when I try to browse to e.g. https://console-openshift-console.apps.my-cluster.local, it knows to query the DNS server

That's the main problem. The standard Linux DNS resolver¹ (the one which handles resolv.conf) is the most basic stub resolver there is: it has no ability to "know" which server to query for which domain name – it completely relies on the server knowing that.
The traditional solution for that has often been to... run Dnsmasq. You'd install Dnsmasq on your workstation, add server= options mapping certain domains to their respective nameservers (such as a remote Dnsmasq), and point your /etc/resolv.conf to the Dnsmasq at your 127.0.0.1.
On larger networks, you'd run a central Dnsmasq to provide DNS resolver service to the whole LAN instead of just the workstation itself, but the idea is the same. Other resolvers can also be used for this purpose, e.g. Unbound or BIND9 with forwarder or static-stub zones.
(I probably wouldn't try to wrangle the OpenShift Dnsmasq into doing this job; let it remain OpenShift-only.)
¹ If you happen to be using systemd-resolved as the OS resolver, it has support for mapping domains to different DNS servers, but such mappings are tied to network interfaces – you'd need to create e.g. dummy0 with its own DNS= and Domains= parameters.
